# Mount share in fstab for multiuser access

Tags: permissions, fstab, shared-folders

I have a network share that is mounted through fstab with the following line:

```
//[url/share] /media/mountpoint cifs credentials=[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=alpha,gid=alpha,nobootwait 0 0
```

This works great on all pcs in our network where `alpha` is the only user.  But there is one pc with two accounts on it, and on that one, it works great for `alpha`, but when `beta` creates a folder on the share, it is owned by `alpha` and the permissions are funky.  I can change the line to `...id=beta,gid=beta...`, then it works for `beta` but not `alpha`.

I tried leaving out the `uid` and setting the `gid` to a group that both `alpha` and `beta` belonged to, but that gave neither of them the desired results.

What's the correct way to mount this share in fstab so that both `alpha` and `beta` can create folders on it and own them?

Answer (score 0):

1. mount without any specific UID.

> //[url/share] /media/mountpoint cifs credentials=[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,nobootwait 0 0

According to [samba](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html) manual:

> uid=arg sets the uid that will own all files or directories on the mounted filesystem when the server does not provide ownership information. It may be specified as either a username or a numeric uid. When not specified, the default is uid 0.

2. As an alternative you can create a new group (sambausergroup), and both users (alfa an beta) to the group, then use that group in fstab.

> //[url/share] /media/mountpoint cifs credentials=[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=alpha,gid=**sambausergroup**,nobootwait 0 0

Comment: Suggestion 1 didn't work.  Folders created on the share were owned by user 'nobody' and users alpha and beta did not have permissions to create files in the folders.  Suggestion 2 is what I already tried as described in my 3rd paragraph, it doesn't work either.

Comment: what ubuntu do you use?